# Problema con php, no funciona por momentos, en otro host

Tags: php, mysql, cpanel

Hace unos dias cambie de host, a uno nuevo banahost, esta muy bien, pero yo vengo de site5 y mis sitios de php no funcionan bien en el nuevo, la pagina de entrada no carga, solo la vista de html y css pero no hace la consulta, todo el problema lo ubique en mi manera de conectar con la base de datos, en mi archivo de conexion pero no entiendo por que esta mal si funcionaba en el host anterior, para verificar comprobe las versiones de php y son las mismas:PHP 5.6 (ea-php56), y base de datos mysql igualmente las mismas, verifique los permisos de toda la carpeta del sitio, son:755 verifique todo, no faltan archivos el problema viene cuando llamo mi funcion de php para conectar con la base de datos:
[image: Linea 42 y 43 de la foto]

me asegure de invocar bien al inicio el archivo de conexion donde tambien me marca error:

[image: primeras 6 lineas]

volvi al archivo de conexion.php para verificar el error, en la linea 36 donde dice: "No se pudo conectar a la base de datos"

[image: Esta casi al final de la foto]

pero al abrir el archivo de menu, me tira esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Según entiendo te cambiaste de un hosting a banahosting, o pasaste de tu localhost a banahosting?

Comment: me cambie de site5 un hosting muy bueno a banahosting, nunca he estado en local

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para la conexión a la base de datos necesitas los cuatro parámetros básicos:
**servidor**, **base de datos**, **usuario** y **password**.
El servidor es el nombre de tu dominio.
La base de datos debes crearla tú desde tu panel de control y desde allí se genera el usuario y password.
Me parece raro que tengas esta declaración `this->servidor = "localhost"` revisa bien tus parámetros de conexión.

Comment: Si lo hice, parece que ese no es el problema, tengo un archivo de los que no abren y tiran 404 not found se llama menu2.php, pero si lo renombro a menudos.php si lo abre hay alguna solucion para esto? @Piropeator